# Math symbol: Vertical bar for ''evaluated at …'' Limits are not apart enough

Tags: math-mode, symbols

[image]

**LaTeX**:

```
\[\int_{a}^{b} f(x)dx = F(b) - F(a) = F(x) \bigg\rvert{_a^b}\]
```

**Question**: The lower and upper limits are showing in the middle of the vertical bar. How can we place these at the lower and upper end of the vertical bar respectively?

**Remark**: Would like to have it done without using extra packages. Default package (e.g. `amsmath`) would be fine.

**UPDATE**: After using `@Bernard`'s suggestion, the expression looks as follows - that seems to have adequate horizontal spacing (unless there are better ideas).

[image]

Comment: Remove the braces around `_a^b`.

Comment: @Bernard Your suggestion worked like a charm (thank you).

Comment: Actually, adding the braces makes the index and exponent be applied  to an empty string, anot to  \biig\vert. B.t.w. you should check whether using `\biggr\vert` has better horizontal spacing.

Comment: @Bernard I've added an **UPDATE** section so you and other readers can judge if horizontal spacing is adequate for my case.

Comment: It's fine for me. I guess the spacing is taken care of by using `\rvert` rather than \vert or |.